# chaining select using jquery.chained.min.js does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to chain select as can be seen in the following. The problem is it is not working. When I select VIC for instance, the ones under VIC does not show up?

I am **using jquery.chained.min.js** as found from here   http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

As the code is really large just adding parts of it below. Complete code is ast jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8gUw4/1/

```
$("#custom1").chained("#state");
```

Above is the js code and below is one of the select

```
<select id="state" name="state">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="NT">NT</option>
    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
    <option value="SA">SA</option>
    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
    <option value="WA">WA</option>
</select>
```

The other select looks similar to below

```
<select id="custom1" name="custom1">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option  value="199346" class="ACT">Ainslie (IGA Ainslie )</option>
  <option  value="182755" class="ACT">Banks (IGA Banks )</option>
  <option  value="182315" class="ACT">Canberra City (City West Carpark IGA Plus Liquor )</option>
  <option  value="182056" class="ACT">Canberra City (IGA X-press East Row )</option>
  <option  value="179370" class="ACT">Chapman (IGA Chapman )</option>
  <option  value="198308" class="ACT">Deakin (IGA Deakin )</option>
  <option  value="171479" class="ACT">Evatt (IGA Evatt )</option>
.....

</select>
```

Comment: The fiddle seems to be working to me. I select `VIC` and the options with `class="VIC"` show up. I see that options with `value=""` also always show up, but maybe that's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: nah not working.. Lets say we chose NT, the options are

  <option  value="83390" class="NT">Alice Springs (Eastside Supermarket IGA )</option>....
  <option  value="83486" class="NT">Yulara (Voyagers Ayers Rock Resort IGA )</option>

HOwever neither of these show up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fiddle seems to be working to me. I select VIC and the options with class="VIC" show up.

Perhaps the problem you're seeing is that some options that don't have a class of `VIC` also show up. This is probably because the ones that show up have an empty value. My guess is that chained filters the options by value, so it is unable to filter the ones with empty values.

Comment: Bit u might be right.. Every option value probably needs a value for this jquery pluging to work.. I am going to try this now and let know soon...I hope

Comment: The `Alice Springs (Eastside Supermarket IGA)` value shows up for me. It's after the options with an empty `value`.

Comment: Yulara is also showing up. These aren't sorted, so maybe you're just not spotting them.

Comment: You are right... Actually the problem was there were a few which did not have any values. That was throwing away everything. Every option needs to have a value associated with it. Those that don't will just end up showing by default always... I think